# how to add suitable library based on cpu architecture in cmake

Tags: x86, cmake, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have a project that relies on some libraries. There are two version of the library

```
myLib.lib 
mylib64.lib
```

and I should add suitable one based on the target platform for the application. How can I do this in cmake?